# Projection field in mongodb for another field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I have the follow example of Json:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "instancia": "1",
    "infoAdicionais": {
        "partes": [{
            "id": "123"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want some mode to put de *partes* array **out of** object, somelike this:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "instancia": "1",
    "partes": [{
            "id": "123"
    }]
}
```

*find* command works? I'm using mongodb 2.0, aggregate function is not available for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that from this [mongodb blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/16015854270/operations-in-the-new-aggregation-framework), aggregation framework is available on mongodb 2.2 including `$project`.

The following will :

- `$project` all fields but `infoAdicionals` & creating a new one with `$infoAdicionais.partes`

In mongo 2.2 query is :

```
db.runCommand({
  aggregate: "device",
  pipeline: [{
    $project: {
      "status": 1,
      "instancia": 1,
      "partes": "$infoAdicionais.partes"
    }
  }]
});
```

In mongo 2.6+ query is :

```
db.device.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    "status": 1,
    "instancia": 1,
    "partes": "$infoAdicionais.partes"
  }
}])
```

In mongo 2.0.0, I iterate each item with a cursor, add a property & remove another :

```
var cursor = db.device.find();

while(cursor.hasNext()){
    var item = cursor.next();
    item.partes=item.infoAdicionais.partes;
    delete item['infoAdicionais'];
    printjsononeline(item);
}
```

Comment: Sorry guy, the version is 2.0

Comment: I've updated my post with a proposition to iterate each item to perform `$project` equivalent